# parent-component-binding with *ngIf on a shared service is not updated when triggered from child component

Tags: angular

I have a **parent** and **child** component. The **parent** component has a menu. When the **child** component says this.service.isMenuVisible(false) the menu is still visible in the parent component. I get no error.

Afair angular checks for updates from **parent** down to the **children** components, that means I try to change an expression after the parent component was checked...

How should I correctly fix that scenario with my shared singleton service?

```
export class RouterService {
  public id: number = 0;
  constructor(private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {

        if (event.url == "/projects/create") {
          console.log(event.url)
         this.setIsMenuVisible(false);
        }
        else {
          console.log(event.url);
          this.setIsMenuVisible(true);
        }

        var first = event.state.root.firstChild.firstChild;
        var id = first && event.state.root.firstChild.firstChild.params['id'];
        this.id = +id;
      }
    });
  }

  private isMenuVisible: BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  setIsMenuVisible(isMenuVisible: Boolean): void
  {
    this.isMenuVisible.next(isMenuVisible);
  }  

  getIsMenuVisible(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this.isMenuVisible.asObservable();
  }

}
```

**PARENT Component**

```
    ngOnInit()
    {
   this.service.id === 0 ? this.service.setIsMenuVisible(false) : this.service.setIsMenuVisible(true);

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mx-4" *ngIf="service.getIsMenuVisible">
...
</ul>
```

**CHILD Component**

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.service.setIsMenuVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your child supply the value for isMenuVisible via an eventemitter to the parent, and have the parent use it to set this.service.isMenuVisible

Comment: Why should that work better than my shared service which already uses an RX Subject? I will add some code!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use a getter in the parent. If you could provide some code for how this isMenuVisible is used know, I can provide an example.

Here is an example of how I use it with my `showImage` flag from my service.

In my component:

```
get showImage(): boolean {
    return this.movieParameterService.displayPosters;
}
set showImage(value: boolean) {
    this.movieParameterService.displayPosters = value;
}
```

This ensures that if the service value changes, the component's change detection will pick up the change and react accordingly.

Now that you've posted some code ... you could change this:

```
  private isMenuVisible: BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  setIsMenuVisible(isMenuVisible: Boolean): void
  {
    this.isMenuVisible.next(isMenuVisible);
  }  

  getIsMenuVisible(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this.isMenuVisible.asObservable();
  }
```

To just this:

```
  isMenuVisible: boolean = false;
```

And then your html would just be this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mx-4" *ngIf="service.isMenuVisible">
```

OR to better encapsulate it:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mx-4" *ngIf="isMenuVisible">
```

And in the component:

```
get isMenuVisible(): boolean {
    return this.service.isMenuVisible;
}
```

Comment: The html directly binds to the service.getIsMenuVisible which returns an observable so it should get the latest value.See my code updates.

Comment: The problem may be here then: ` *ngIf="service.getIsMenuVisible"` should be ` *ngIf="service.getIsMenuVisible()"` (with parenthesis on it). But note that a `BehaviorSubject` is not really needed here. You could instead do it with a simple property and a getter as I showed above.

Comment: I have many uses cases where a simple property setter/getter does not work. Browser reload, url param change, hide menu via action items create/edit.

Comment: Perfect! I've been racking my brain trying to come up with a scenario whereby BehaviorSubject was needed. Every example I can come up with could more simply be coded with a getter. Would it be possible to converse with you more about this outside of SO? Maybe private message on twitter? I want to do a blog post/article/course on this topic and need some good examples.

Comment: Thanks for being obstinately... only because of that I tried your suggestion! I do not know why and I hope I tested all uses cases, but with a normal boolean property the parent component is updated triggered by the child component via shared service! Thank you! I will have to think about this...

Comment: Great! And bummer because I was hoping you'd found an example for me. In all seriousness, I *am* looking for a good example of when we *must* use a `BehaviorSubject`. If you do stumble upon an example, I'd like to hear about it! (And the "why" has to do with Angular's change detection. Maybe this helps: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Comment: You look for why a BehaviorSubject vs Subject OR Why a BehaviorSubject at all when a simple property works? Damn... it does NOT work, I get this error in the console log which I overlooked - that was my assumption from the beginning - =>  ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

Comment: I was hoping to cover: no subject (simple properties), Subject, BehaviorSubject, and ReplaySubject and when to use each. But having trouble coming up with realistic examples for the `xxxSubject`. I know when to use which of the `xxxSubject` ... but can't find a common scenario to demonstrate them.

Comment: Pls see my edited comment! I get the above error directly in the html: *ngIf="isMenuVisible"

Comment: So maybe the answer to my question is "any time the data changes more quickly than the change detection can execute"? I wonder if we could build a plunker that demonstrates this?

Comment: When you look for that error in google it clearly says that I can not change the expression of the parent component after it was checked because that would leave inconsistent UI. :-/ See comment from 'robwormald' https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572 Hm... and this error goes away in production? not sure wether I understand this correctly...

Comment: I use this getter technique everywhere ... but may not have the same types of code as you. I'm thinking I have not tried it between a parent and its child (nested) component. So a plunker would be really nice to see if you have a moment ...

Comment: Not today going to bed now cu tomorrow... Not my sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/OdkzHjEXbEd3efYAisFM?p=preview same use case as mine...

Comment: Just FYI ... as per some of the discussion on this topic at the link you provided ... the issue is often resolved by changing *when* the value is set. I modified the plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/GQkizhg6G5HiXtzXtBFM?p=preview I'm not sure if that is possible in your particular scenario.

Comment: that will only work in my case when the edit/create button in the parent component is triggered then I can directly hide the menu. This will not work on browser refresh/url change :-/